# WordPress AJAX admin-ajax.php Pagination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am at a wall here. I am updating my search result using ajax like so :

```
function ajax_search_enqueues() {
if ( is_search() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-search', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom/ajax-search.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-search', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_search_enqueues' );
```

I am triggering the ajax call on an input change with this

```
jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').on( 'change', function() {

    var cat = jQuery(this).attr('name');

    if (this.checked) {
        cats.push(cat);
    } else {
        cats.splice(cats.indexOf(cat), 1);
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'load_search_results',
            categories: cats,
            s: s
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            jQuery( ".content").empty().append( data );
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

} );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_search_results', 'load_search_results' );
```

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_search_results', 'load_search_results' );
add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'breed_posts_nav' );

and calling the functions like so

```
function load_search_results() {
get_template_part( 'loop', 'grid' );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    's' => $_GET['s'],
    'category__in' =>$_GET['categories'],
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
);

// doing loop stuff 

die();
}
```

I am retrieving all information properly besides pagination. The reason pagination breaks is because I am filtering by category. So on the left hand side I have category checkboxes and when a checkbox is changed it triggers the ajax request. I can get the pagination to update but when clicking on the page number the url is directed to `http://dev:8888/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=load_search_results/blah/blah/blah` this breaks the page and is no longer on the search.php page.  Is there a way to use pagination using ajax? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you have some sort of global ajax interceptor modifying the url. Worst case you could try manually creating the url string. Or find the ajax interceptor method and adjust it

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
filter.js
---------
$('#post-category').change(function(){
        category = $(this).find('.selected').text();
        postType = $('#search-form-type').val();
        post_filter();
    });


function post_filter(paged){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url:ajaxUrl,
                type:"POST",
                data: {action:"get_post_category","category":category,'search':search, 'postType':postType, 'paged': paged},
                success: function(response) {
                $('#blog-post-cover').html(response);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#blog-wrapper').on('click','#pagination a',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();     
        if ($(this).hasClass('prev')||$(this).hasClass('next')) {
            paginateNum = $(this).find('.prev-next').data('attr');
            post_filter(paginateNum);
        }
        else{
            paginateNum = $(this).text();
            post_filter(paginateNum);
        }
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    });
    postType = $('#search-form-type').val();
    post_filter(1);

function.php
------------

/*  ==========================================================================
     Blog filter
    ========================================================================== */

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_category', 'post_category' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_post_category', 'post_category' );   
    function post_category() {
        $post_type = $_POST['postType'];      
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        $paged = ($_POST['paged'])? $_POST['paged'] : 1;
        if($post_type==="resource-center"):
            $taxonomy ="resource-center-taxonomy";
        else:
            $taxonomy ="category";
        endif;
        if($category):
            $args = array(
                'post_type'         => $post_type,
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $category,
                    ),
                ),
                'posts_per_page'    => 5,
                'order'             => 'ASC',
                's'                 => $search,
                'paged'             => $paged
            );
        else:
            $args = array(
                'post_type'         => $post_type,
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'    => 5,
                'order'             => 'ASC',
                's'                 => $search,
                'paged'             => $paged
            );
        endif;

        $posts = new WP_Query($args);?>
        <?php if ( $posts->have_posts() ) :?>
            <?php while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
        <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            <?php
                $nextpage = $paged+1;
                $prevouspage = $paged-1;
                $total = $posts->max_num_pages;
                $pagination_args = array(
                'base'               => '%_%',
                'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
                'total'              => $total,
                'current'            => $paged,
                'show_all'           => false,
                'end_size'           => 1,
                'mid_size'           => 2,
                'prev_next'          => true,
                'prev_text'       => __('<span class="prev-next" data-attr="'.$prevouspage.'">&laquo;</span>'),
                'next_text'       => __('<span class="prev-next" data-attr="'.$nextpage.'">&raquo;</span>'),
                'type'               => 'plain',
                'add_args'           => false,
                'add_fragment'       => '',
                'before_page_number' => '',
                'after_page_number'  => ''
            );
            $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

            if ($paginate_links) {
                echo "<div id='pagination' class='pagination'>";
                echo $paginate_links;
                echo "</div>";
            }?>
            <?php wp_reset_query();  ?>
        <?php else:?>           
           <div class="no-post-cover">
                <div class="container">         
                   <h1 class="has-no-post-list">Posts Not Found</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
       <?php endif;?>         
       <?php die(1);
    }
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to your answer.

Comment: you need to pass paginateNum  through ajax so that you can get  $nextpage = $paged+1;
$prevouspage = $paged-1;
$total = $posts->max_num_pages;